# How to alter a Rules Core Condition?

Tags: rules

I need to use the core condition 'Entity has field' but without the selection list restriction.

Easiest way to implement this is to wipe out the two restrictions manually. But how do I do this in a more persistent way - surviving module updates?

Original code:

```
function rules_entity_condition_info() {
  return array(
 //other stuff
'entity_has_field' => array(
  'label' => t('Entity has field'),
  'parameter' => array(
    'entity' => array(
      'type' => 'entity',
      'label' => t('Entity'),
      'description' => t('Specifies the entity for which to evaluate the condition.'),
      'restriction' => 'selector',
    ),
    'field' => array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => t('Field'),
      'description' => t('The name of the field to check for.'),
      'options list' => 'rules_condition_entity_has_field_options',
      'restriction' => 'input',
    ),
  ),
  'group' => t('Entities'),
  'base' => 'rules_condition_entity_has_field',
),
//more stuff
);
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much every `info` hook has an `alter` counterpart. `hook_rules_condition_info` is no exception so you should be able to do something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_rules_condition_info_alter(&$conditions) {
  // Change something
  $conditions['entity_has_field']['field']['restriction'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally forgot to check the _alter. /Leiph